# Find biggest liquidity pool of token for swap on Pancakeswap

Tags: pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I am coding a bot can buy - sell token in Pancakeswap. I already found a way to do it. But problem is 1 token has many liquidity pool, and I don't know which is the biggest.

Example: token Address: 0x20d39a5130f799b95b55a930e5b7ebc589ea9ed8

It's has 3 LP which is, HE/BNB, HE/BUSD, HE/USDT. And HE/BUSD is the biggest with 330k$.
If I swap token with USDT or BNB, my transition will fail because the liquidity pool is too small.

So I ask for a way to find it.
Thanks for advice !